# Why is composer trying to install the Drupal 8.2.x-dev branch?

Tags: 8, composer

### UPDATE: I am not going to continue to troubleshoot this.  Composer is working OK in my local site, so I'm going to change my approach to deployment and stop running composer in my staging site.  Instead I will run composer locally, commit core & vendor to the git project, and deploy all code to staging with git.

---

If I run composer install, I get...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

However, in the require section of my composer.json, I have...

```
"drupal/core": "8.6.13"
```

So why is composer trying to install 8.2.x-dev?

**UPDATE:** It was suggested I run "composer why drupal/core".  Here is the output from that command...

drupal/acquia_connector               1.16.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/address                        1.6.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.6)
drupal/admin_menu_search              1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/admin_toolbar                  1.26.0         requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/advagg                         3.5.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/advagg_css_minify              3.5.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/advagg_js_minify               3.5.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/allowed_formats                1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/asset_injector                 2.4.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/backup_migrate                 4.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/better_exposed_filters         3.0.0-alpha6   requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/block_field                    1.0.0-alpha8   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/block_visibility_groups        1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/block_visibility_groups_admin  1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/business_core                  3.0.0-alpha2   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/config_installer               1.8.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/config_update                  1.6.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/contact_block                  1.4.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/content_export_csv             3.0.0-beta2    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/content_sync                   2.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/contentimport                  4.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/contribute                     5.0.0-beta3    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/crop                           1.5.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/ctools                         3.2.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.5)

drupal/devel                          2.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/dropzonejs                     2.0.0-alpha3   requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/dropzonejs_eb_widget           2.0.0-alpha3   requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/drupal                         dev-master     requires  drupal/core (8.6.13)

drupal/embed                          1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/encrypt                        3.0.0-rc2      requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/entity                         1.0.0-rc2      requires  drupal/core (^8.6)

drupal/entity_browser                 2.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/entity_clone                   1.0.0-beta3    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/entity_embed                   1.0.0-beta2    requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/entity_reference_revisions     1.6.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/entity_reference_views_select  1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/entityqueue                    1.0.0-beta1    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/event                          dev-1.x        requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/facets                         1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/features                       3.8.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/field_group                    1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/file_browser                   1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/form_placeholder               1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/formblock                      1.0.0-beta9    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/glazed_helper                  1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/google_analytics               3.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.5)

drupal/honeypot                       1.29.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/image_widget_crop              2.2.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/imce                           1.7.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/imce_search                    1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/imce_search_plugin             1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/inline_entity_form             1.0.0-rc1      requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/insert_block                   dev-1.x        requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/job                            3.0.0-alpha2   requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/key                            1.8.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/linkit                         4.3.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/login_emailusername            1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/material_admin                 1.0.0-alpha7   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/media_bulk_upload              1.0.0-alpha24  requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/media_entity                   1.8.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/media_entity_browser           1.0.0-beta3    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/memcache                       2.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/menu_link_attributes           1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/metatag                        1.8.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/migrate_file                   1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/migrate_plus                   4.1.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.3)

drupal/migrate_source_csv             2.2.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.1)

drupal/migrate_tools                  4.1.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.3)

drupal/minifyhtml                     1.7.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/module_missing_message_fixer   1.0.0-beta2    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/paragraphs                     1.8.0          requires  drupal/core (~8)
drupal/pathauto                       1.4.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.5)
drupal/purge                          3.0.0-beta8    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/purge_processor_lateruntime    3.0.0-beta8    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/purge_purger_http              1.0.0-beta4    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/purge_tokens                   3.0.0-beta8    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/purge_ui                       3.0.0-beta8    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/redirect                       1.3.0          requires  drupal/core (~8)
drupal/require_login                  2.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/rules                          3.0.0-alpha4   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/search_api                     1.12.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.5)
drupal/search_api_solr                1.2.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/simple_sitemap                 3.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/simplenews                     1.0.0-alpha3   requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/smtp                           1.0.0-beta4    requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/taxonomy_access_fix            2.6.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/text_summary_options           1.0.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/tfa                            1.0.0-alpha4   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/token                          1.5.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.5)
drupal/twig_tweak                     2.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/typed_data                     1.0.0-alpha3   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/video_embed_field              2.0.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/view_unpublished               1.0.0-alpha1   requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/viewport                       1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/views_bulk_operations          2.5.0          requires  drupal/core (^8.4)
drupal/views_infinite_scroll          1.5.0          requires  drupal/core (*)

drupal/viewsreference                 1.4.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/we_megamenu                    1.5.0          requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

drupal/webform                        5.2.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/workflow                       1.1.0          requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/workflow_state_config          1.0.0-alpha2   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/xmlsitemap                     1.0.0-alpha3   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)

Comment: `composer why drupal/core` might help

Comment: `composer why-not drupal/core ^8.6` provides slightly different info that may also help

Comment: @Clive I ran that command, and also ran it like "composer why drupal/core 8.2.x-dev", but it's not obvious to me what to do with the output.  I don't see any references to "drupal/core 8.2.x-dev" in the output.

Comment: @gapple I ran the why-not command like you suggested, and the output is 'There is no installed package depending on "drupal/core" in versions not matching ^8.6'.  I'm not sure if that tells me anything useful?  Thanks.

Comment: The `why-not` output seems to indicate that there isn't a restriction that should prevent installing 8.6.  Sharing the output from `why` in your question would be helpful.

Comment: @gapple I added an update to the question that includes the `why` output.  Thanks.